# Single Tap works fine in other device but not in every device using android studio

Tags: android, touch-event

I am working on a project that uses  **onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)** to handle single tap event when i tap the screen it will hide a button and reappear when you tap again. I am very new to android. The app works fine on my lg device that runs on Kitkat but not on my samsung that runs on Lollipop. I have spent almost 2 days researching this but no luck. This how i did it...

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            return false;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            x1 = event.getX();
            y1 = event.getY();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            x2 = event.getX();
            y2 = event.getY();

            diffx = x2 - x1;
            diffy = y2 - y1;

            boolean sameX = x2 + tolerance > event.getX() && x2 - tolerance < event.getX();
            boolean sameY = y2 + tolerance > event.getY() && y2 - tolerance < event.getY();
            if (sameX && sameY) {

                if (gone == false) {

                    pages.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    lib.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    final Animation slide_out_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_up);
                    lib.startAnimation(slide_out_up);

                    final Animation slide_out_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_down);
                    pages.startAnimation(slide_out_down);

                    gone = true;
                } else {

                    pages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    lib.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    final Animation slide_in_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_down);
                    lib.startAnimation(slide_in_down);

                    final Animation slide_in_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_up);
                    pages.startAnimation(slide_in_up);
                    gone = false;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

and this is my gradle...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.civitas.christian.fragments"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'}
```

i really need help badly..

Comment: why are you using touch event...instead of button click?

Comment: @HetalUpadhyay i guess because of ==== >>>when i tap the screen it will hide a button and reappear when you tap again.

Comment: ok...you want on screen tap not button...right?

Comment: have you registered your touch event with parent view?

Comment: @christian once please check answer it may help you.

Comment: @user1140237 the thing is everything works fine on my other device that runs on kitkat but won't work on my device running on lollipop..that is why i added the gradle file because i might have miss something on it..

Answer (score 0):

You can modify [onTouchEvent](http://goo.gl/F1oZ8B) to handle other controls click and touch

```
public class MYTest extends FragmentActivity {
    Button btnShowHide;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        btnShowHide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowHide);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            //If you wants to use animation start animation here 
            // & you can show/hide object on end animation
            if (btnShowHide.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

                btnShowHide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                btnShowHide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        //// Based on the requirement you can give return boolean
        // to handle click & other controls touch event
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

For Animation Start & end callback listner please check [AnimationListener](http://goo.gl/U9DUwm)